# How to remove PPA _compholio_

Tags: ppa

I trying to remove this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ehoover/+archive/ubuntu/compholio) without results.

I've Debian 8 as OS and want to remove the PPA since after running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it gives the error `W: Failed to fetch  http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found`

By running `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` I do not find the corresponding PPA e trying to remove it by running sudo add-apt-repository to update the package or sudo ppa-purge to delete it I don't get a solution.

Could someone suggest any solution to this problem?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant files for ppa's are unter /etc/apt/sources.list.d.

`apt-add-repository -r ppa:ehoover/compholio` And avoid Ubunu-ppa's unter Debian. Debian !=Ubuntu. :D